# Swap start_time with end_time (vice versa) in a table using R

Tags: r, lubridate, swap, mutate, absolute-value

I am dealing with a bike sharing data set and in its raw data, the start_time has been keyed in with the end_time and vice versa. [start time is later than end time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKDYG.jpg)

Is there a way I can swap the two columns for the affected rows or is there a way to get an absolute result when I use start_time - end_time?

this was what I did to get the ride duration (start_time - end_time):

```
#new column to show ride duration
# step 1 change type to what we want dttm
Q4_2019 <- Q4_2019 %>% 
  mutate(start_time = as_datetime(start_time)) %>% 
  mutate (end_time = as_datetime(end_time))
# step 2 create new column showing ride_duration
Q4_2019 <- Q4_2019 %>% 
  mutate(ride_duration = end_time - start_time)
```

```
df <- structure(list(trip_id = c(25625850, 25625849, 25625851, 25625843, 
25625841, 25625838, 25625830, 25625839, 25241500, 25293548, 25380297, 
25382592, 25425647, 25432182, 25447046, 25535424, 25539306), 
    start_time = structure(c(1572746268, 1572746133, 1572746297, 
    1572745919, 1572745831, 1572745669, 1572745401, 1572745684, 
    1569960882, 1570290715, 1570747626, 1570782378, 1571127078, 
    1571158556, 1571248410, 1571846602, 1571854341), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), end_time = structure(c(1572742886, 
    1572742912, 1572743307, 1572742982, 1572743065, 1572742960, 
    1572743396, 1572743808, 1569960943, 1570290776, 1570747687, 
    1570782439, 1571127139, 1571158617, 1571248471, 1571846663, 
    1571854402), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    bikeid = c(217, 5059, 6133, 2920, 4179, 964, 4141, 2214, 
    6029, 2081, 5397, 976, 6130, 3819, 1725, 6372, 6058), tripduration = c(5310, 
    379, 609, 663, 834, 891, 1594, 1724, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 
    61, 61, 61, 61), from_station_id = c(340, 109, 301, 460, 
    298, 229, 632, 131, 293, 76, 328, 308, 664, 174, 77, 91, 
    253)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

Comment: When swapping the values held in two variables, you need to use a third variable to temporarily hold the value in the first after it's been over written by the second.  To take an absolute value, look at the `abs()` function.  PS  You can mutate more than one column in a single call.

Comment: Hi @Limey, thanks for responding! I will look into the abs() function to get an absolute value. May i ask if you can show me how I can mutate 2 columns: start_time & end_time using a single call? Greatly appreciate that!!

Comment: `mutate(start_time = as_datetime(start_time), end_time = as_datetime(end_time))`

Comment: Thanks! @PaulStaffordAllen. May I check if you know what went wrong here: Q4_2019 <- Q4_2019 %>% 
  mutate(ride_duration = abs(end_time) - abs(start_time))? I tried using the abs() recommended by @Limey, but I got this error message: Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `ride_duration = abs(end_time) - abs(start_time)`.
Caused by error in `Math.POSIXt()`:
! 'abs' not defined for "POSIXt" objects

Comment: a way of doing this with `mutate` is `mutate(start = as_datetime(end_time), end = as_datetime(start_time), .keep = "unused")`

Comment: But I am trying to get a positive / absolute value because some of the rows in this dataframe have start_time later than end_time. so when I am trying to get the difference, I have some negative values. Do you happen to know how I can swap the data around so that start time is later than end time for the affected rows? @G.Grothendieck

Comment: to get the absolute value of something, you can use `abs()`, but it's good practice to have the data organised before you start analysing it

Comment: `transform` from base R is like `mutate` but on the RHS will use the state of the variables as they existed before the `transform` so this will work without a third variable: `Q4_2019 %>%
  transform(start_time = pmin(start_time, end_time), end_time = pmax(start_time, end_time))`

Comment: The start time should be an earlier time than the end time. But for 8 observations out of the 600K observations have start time later than end time. This will result in a negative difference (for the 8 obs) when I try to create a new column to find out the ride duration (end - start).

Comment: maybe something like this, if you wish to use mutate: mutate(df, start = if_else(as_datetime(start_time) > as_datetime(end_time), as_datetime(end_time), as_datetime(start_time)),
       end = if_else(as_datetime(start_time) > as_datetime(end_time), as_datetime(start_time), as_datetime(end_time)), .keep = "unused")

Comment: To sum up the previous comments, there are two options you can try: (1) `Q4_2019 %>% mutate(start = pmin(start_time, end_time), end = pmax(start_time, end_time), ride_duration = end - start)` (2) If you only care about the duration, `Q4_2019 %>% mutate(ride_duration = abs(end_time - start_time))`

Comment: I added reproducible input :-)

Comment: @DarrenTsai the issue with the first one is it creates two new columns, unless you add a .keep = "unused"

Comment: yeah sure! so the long version can be found [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html#arguments). The short version is, when you run mutate, you can tell it to keep only certain columns. One of the options is to only keep unused columns, which means that all of the columns you used as arguments in the mutate function (start_time and end_time) are dropped, but everything other column is kept, (as well as the columns you created)

Comment: @Mark thanks! it worked! I read in the comments you mentioned that .keep="unused" is something about not creating new columns. Can you explain a bit more on that? if with the mutate code you provided, I don't put .keep="unused", will it still work?

Comment: it will still work, but it will keep the unprocessed start_time and end_time columns, which you might not want. See my comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

# using mutate
df %>%
  mutate(diff = abs(difftime(start_time, end_time)),
         start_time = pmin(start_time, end_time), # credit to Darren Tsai for pmin idea :-) 
         end_time = start_time + diff) %>%
  select(-diff) # you can delete this (and the last %>%) if you want to keep the diff column 

# using transform (credit to G. Grothendieck)
df %>%
  transform(start_time = pmin(start_time, end_time),
            end_time = pmax(start_time, end_time))
```